# Currency Converter using two checkedlistbox c#, vb 2010

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

i am a bit new in c# and i have an assignment  to do:

Can some one can help me with the code of the button, of how to convert from USD to EUR?

That is what have a done till now:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '.')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        // only allow one decimal point
        if (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

      private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
       {
              for (int ix = 0; ix < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; ++ix)
               if (ix != e.Index) checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(ix, false);

         }

      private void checkedListBox2_ItemCheck(object sender,                           ItemCheckEventArgs e)
      {
          for (int ix = 0; ix < checkedListBox2.Items.Count; ++ix)
            if (ix != e.Index) checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(ix, false);

      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

      }

}
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `checkedListBox` to convert from USD to EUR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what are the `checkListBox`es are used for, but you can convert from USD to EUR this way:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        textBox1.Text =  (Double.Parse(textBox1.Text) * 0.88).ToString(); // 0.88 EUR = 1 USD
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Use the `try` statement so the program won't crash if you insert something that can't be parsed to `Double`

If you want the result to show only 2 digits after the dot, you can use `textBox1.Text = (Math.Round(Double.Parse(textBox1.Text) * 0.88, 2)).ToString();`

### EDIT

So I was bored and looked for something to do and decided I'll script some currency converter for you to learn something about `ComboBox` from. There it is then:

```
double[] dcurrency = { 1, 1.13, 1.52 }; // Currency conversion to USD (By order: USD, EUR, GBP)
double[] currency = { 1, 0.88, 0.66 }; // Currency conversion from USD (By order: USD, EUR, GBP)
string[] currencies = { "USD", "EUR", "GBP" };
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(currencies);
    comboBox2.Items.AddRange(currencies);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        textBox2.Text = "ERROR";
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        double c1 = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        textBox2.Text = (c1 * dcurrency[comboBox1.SelectedIndex] * currency[comboBox2.SelectedIndex]).ToString();
    }
    catch { textBox2.Text = "ERROR"; }
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == comboBox2.SelectedIndex)
    {
        ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedIndex = -1;
        textBox2.Text = "ERROR";
        return;
    }
    if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 && comboBox2.SelectedIndex > -1)
        button1_Click(button1, e);
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 && comboBox2.SelectedIndex > -1)
        button1_Click(button1, e);
}
```

}

It uses two `TextBox`es - `textBox1` and `textBox2` and two `ComboBox`es - `comboBox1` and `comboBox2`. `private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` is one event for both of the `ComboBox`es. It updates the conversion automatically when the text changes and when one of the `ComboBox`'s index has changed.

I used two `Double` arrays because it's simpler to always convert the value to USD and then to the correct currency using the `ComboBox`'s indexes instead of writing lots of `if` statements and checks for every possibility. It's important that the indexes of the `Double` arrays and the `ComboBox`es will be adjusted for the same currency (0 = USD, 1 = EUR, 2 = GBP etc..). Also, I used a `String` array for the `ComboBox`'s items just to show you how it's written. You may also insert those items within the properties menu of each `ComboBox` instead. Enjoy learning!

Comment: This was helpful, thank you, my  real problem is how to get the element from checkedlistbox 1 and from checkedlistbox 2 and then to convert it, something like this:
checkedbox1:      checkedbox2:
EUR                      EUR
USD                      USD
GBP                      GBP

If EUR is checked from 1 and if USD is checked from 2 then convert.

Comment: I would suggest using a `ComboBox`, because in `CheckedListBox` you can select multiple choices while in ComboBox you choose one from a list of items.

Comment: I have added some currency converter code so you can understand how to use `ComboBox`.

Comment: Thank you, Aradmey, i tried this code and doing a little modification with checkedlistbox and it works great. This was very helpful